# How to get custom validator event to fire in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, customvalidator

I am using custom validator tool in asp.net to check whether a text box is blank or not(I did not use requiredfieldvalidator because the text box in question is going to be enabled occasionally).The problem is that the custom validator event in code behind is not firing at all.This is the source code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtS_rentSDate" runat="server" Font-Names="Bookman Old Style" 
                Font-Size="Medium" Width="326px" 
                ontextchanged="txtS_rentSDate_TextChanged" 
                CausesValidation="True"></asp:TextBox>    

<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRentSDate" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtS_rentSDate" 
                ErrorMessage="Please enter the rent start date" 
                onservervalidate="cvRentSDate_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="True" 
                Width="180px"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void cvRentSDate_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (args.Value.Length > 0);
}
```

Kindly let me know where I am going wrong and what is the proper way to do it?

Comment: Is the page posted back at all? Ie do other events fire?

Comment: Yes, the other events do fire.

Comment: Does your form has any other control than above ? It may possible that some of control you might have used Required Validator or some other validator that work on client side. If this is the case then your event only fire when post back happen.

Comment: @dotnetstep There are other required field validators also, but the postback does happen when the save button is clicked, yet the event is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvRentSDate" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="txtS_rentSDate" 
            ErrorMessage="Please enter the rent start date" 
            OnServerValidate="cvRentSDate_ServerValidate" ValidateEmptyText="True" 
            Width="180px"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Try with my above lines. May be you need to use OnServerValidate instead of onservervalidate.

Comment: It should work. Are you getting any error ?. What is there in txtS_rentSDate_TextChanged event ?

Comment: txtS_rentSDate_TextChanged is blank,it contains nothing.@gkrishy